# How to generate a step-wise function over a Fourier interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ for a piecewise function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have the following piecewise function:

```
y[t_] == Piecewise[{{2, -2 < x < -1}, {1, -1 < x < 0}, {2, 
     0 < x < 1}, {3, 1 < x < 2}}];
```

This is shown here:

[image]

Then I need to produce the same function stretched over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

I try as:

```
y1[t_] = y[(-Pi + 2*Pi*t/4)];
```

but the function is still on the same interval:

[image]

What went wrong?  Each coordinate on the *t*-axis, call it $t_j$ is related to the new interval by $t_j=-\pi+\frac{2\pi}{n}j$. Here $n=4$, since there are 4 indicator functions within the piecewise function.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `==` for the definition of function. Change the definition of `y[t]` to `y[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, -2 < x < -1}, {1, -1 < x < 0}, {2, 
     0 < x < 1}, {3, 1 < x < 2}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
y[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, -2 < x < -1}, {1, -1 < x < 0}, {2,0 < x < 1}, {3, 1< x < 2}}]
Y[u_] := y[u 2/Pi ]
Plot[Y[u], {u, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrich!!

Comment: You're welcome!